# QT6 Insists on using cdb instead of gdb

Tags: c++, qt, gdb

I am using Qt 6.0.4 in Win10, the 'Help/About' says QtCreator version is 4.15.0. I have a very simple desktop application, built using CMake, and using QCustomPlot that crashes. I am using the Kit Qt 6.0.4 mingw81_64. When I look into the settings under manage kits, I see the debugger is supposedly set to 'GNU gdb 8.1 for MinGW 8.1.0 64Bit'. But when I start debugging, I get a message box that seems to indicate it is using cdb, not gdb. In the Debuggers tab for the kit, it shows all the GNU gdb debuggers, but also to CDB, all auto-detected. I can not remove the cdb entries, at least not that I can figure out. How do I turn off cdb so it only uses the gdb that seems to be called for in the kit settings??

[image]

My CMakeLists.txt file is:

```
project(QT60DataAcq VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# QtCreator supports the following variables for Android, which are identical to qmake Android variables.
# Check https://doc.qt.io/qt/deployment-android.html for more information.
# They need to be set before the find_package( ...) calls below.

#if(ANDROID)
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
#    if (ANDROID_ABI STREQUAL "armeabi-v7a")
#        set(ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS
#            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/libcrypto.so
#            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/libssl.so)
#    endif()
#endif()

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 COMPONENTS Widgets PrintSupport REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Widgets PrintSupport REQUIRED)

include_directories(C:/Pgms/Qt/QCUSTOMPLOT2X)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
  main.cpp
  dacqmain.cpp
  dacqmain.h
  dacqmain.ui
C:/Pgms/Qt/QCUSTOMPLOT2X/qcustomplot.cpp
)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(QT60DataAcq
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(QT60DataAcq SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    else()
        add_executable(QT60DataAcq
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()
endif()

target_link_libraries(QT60DataAcq PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::PrintSupport)

set_target_properties(QT60DataAcq
  PROPERTIES
  ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/
  LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/
  RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/
  )

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(QT60DataAcq)
endif()
```